# How to alter format on a single page

Tags: information-management

How can you alter a title on a single page for instance to change colour or be in bold without changing all other titles

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the 'title' you want to be different is exactly one, e.g.

```
<h2>MyTitleNeedsToBeBold</h2>
```

than you either change it directly:

```
<h2 style="font-weight:bold;">MyTitleNeedsToBeBold</h2>
```

or via id-based CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_themes/myStyles.css"/>
<h2 id="mySpecialTitle">MyTitleNeedsToBeBold</h2>
```

and have the following in your css file

```
#mySpecialTitle {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

If you need this for all h2 tags:

```
h2 {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

If you need it for some tags use the class attribute, etc. etc.

A nice CSS reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can apply changes to a single page by adding CSS into a Content Editor Web Part.

Add the CEWP to the page, click the link "Click here to add new content", then in the ribbon in the Markup section click HTML > Edit HTML Source and add your CSS there.